# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer upon function call in express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express backend developed for my app. Upon posting a request to my app route I get an error

> "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of
> type string or Buffer."

This error occurs when trying to access a function through the request route.

Here is the code

```
app.post('/api/orderEmail', (req, res) => {
  //TODO
  console.log('Backend breakpoint');
  console.log(req.body);
  sendEmail(req.body.mail, req.body.name, "thanks"); // function call that generates error
});
```

sendEmail's definition goes by:

```
const sendEmail = (to, name, type) => {
      

    const smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "xxusernamexx",
            pass: "xxpasswordxx"
        }
    })

    const mail = getEmailData(to, name, type)

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
        console.log("sendmail breakpoint");
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log( " email sent successfully")
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
    })


}
```

Comment: what's sendEmail's definition?

Comment: @ewong check up the edit

Comment: what's getEmailData?